# Failed to process build result for "index.py". Data: {"type":"Lambda"}. | Error: data is too long

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, vercel

I get an error while trying to deploy a Flask app. I'm trying to deploy an API that uses the PyTorch model. Is there any possible solution for this?

I just want to run a model and do some experiments with it and play with it with Flask API.

I deployed my app on Vercel and after about 14mins I got this error:

```
Failed to process build result for "index.py". Data: {"type":"Lambda"}.
| Error: data is too long
```

vercel.json:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "./index.py",
            "use": "@vercel/python"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "/"
        }
    ]
}
```

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, send_file
from PIL import Image
import io
from gan_runner import load_model, img_to_tensor, scale

app = Flask(__name__)

ALLOWED_FILETYPES = ["png", "jpg", "jpeg"]


def allowed(filename):
    return "." in filename and filename.rsplit(".", 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_FILETYPES


MODEL = load_model()


@app.route("/upscale", methods=["POST"])
def upscale():
    img_file = request.files.get("img")

    # Check that a file was given
    if img_file is None or img_file.filename == "":
        return jsonify({"error": "No file was provided."})
    if not allowed(img_file.filename):
        return jsonify({"error": "Only image files are allowed"})

    # Read and upscale the image with the model
    img_bytes = img_file.read()
    img_LR = img_to_tensor(img_bytes)
    output = scale(img_LR, MODEL)

    # Return the upscaled image as raw bytes
    result_img = Image.fromarray(output.astype("uint8"))
    rawBytes = io.BytesIO()
    result_img.save(rawBytes, "PNG")
    rawBytes.seek(0)

    return send_file(rawBytes, mimetype="image/PNG")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably hitting the maximum size allowed for your function, most likely because of the gan-runner dependency.

Comment: Maybe i also tried a simple code that uses audiocraft model by Meta, I faced same issue. Can you please tell what to do now? where to deploy API that uses audiocraft model by meta? any free service would be helpful or any other way or solution to just play with the API while playing